# How can I prove this statement?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-writing, induction

I wanted to prove this using induction, but since the RHS is a sum, I can't use the assumption. Therefore I'm stuck in the middle. Is there maybe a way proving that without induction?

If induction is the only way, can you give any hints please? Especially how to get rid of the sum on the RHS?

$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You will want to do it by induction. For the induction step, notice that if you replace $n$ by $n+1$, you add

$$(-1)^{2n+2}\frac1{2n+1}+(-1)^{2n+3}\frac1{2n+2}=\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2n+2}$$

to the lefthand expression, and on the right you add

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{n+1+k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}=\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\frac1{n+k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}\;.\tag{1}$$

The difference on the righthand side of $(1)$ allow a *lot* of telescoping. In fact, you should end up with just three terms.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how you got your term on the right hand side (1)? I put $n+1$ in for $n$ but I don't get what you got.

Comment: @Arthur: Do you mean the first summation, $\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\frac1{n+k}$?

Comment: I mean the whole line (1). I get $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+1+k}+\frac{1}{2n+2}$. Where does your $-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$ come from?

Comment: @Arthur: I’m not simply evaluating the righthand side of your equation with $n$ replaced by $n+1$: I’m calculating how much that change *adds* to the righthand side, just as my first calculation shows how much it adds to the lefthand side of your equation. Thus, my first summation in $(1)$ is the righthand side for $n+1$, and I’m subtracting the righthand side for $n$ to get the increase.

Comment: I'm still confused... I have this so far for the induction step: $(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k})+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}=(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k})+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$. Should I subtract the right hand side now?

Comment: @Arthur: For the induction step you want to show that the two sides of your equation change by the same amount when you increase $n$ to $n+1$: then if they started equal (your induction hypothesis), they must end up equal. In my answer I showed how to calculate how much each side changes; you just have to show that those amounts really are equal.

Comment: I think I got it now. Are the three remaining terms $\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: @Arthur: Not quite, though I think that you may have the right general idea: the first sum does have two extra terms, but they’re the $k=n+1$ and $k=n+2$ terms, so they’re $\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}$; with that as a model, can you fix the third term?

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: @Arthur: Looks good!

Comment: @Arthur: You’re welcome!